Confusion about representing elements as pure tensors in the definition of the tensor product of dg-algebras
I'm refamiliarizing myself with the tensor product of dg-algebras and struggling to reconcile some of the basic definitions. Let $(A, d_A)$ and $(B, d_B)$ be dg-algebras over a field $k$, and assume that $A^n, B^n = 0$ for all $n<0$. The components of $A\otimes B$ are defined as
$$(A\otimes B)^n = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} A^p\otimes B^q  \tag{1}$$
and the differential $d_{A\otimes B}:(A\otimes B)^n\to (A\otimes B)^{n+1}$ is given by
$$d_{A\otimes B}(a\otimes b) = d_A(a)\otimes b +(-1)^{|a|}a\otimes d_B(b)  \tag{2}$$
Where I'm having trouble is how you can represent elements as pure tensors when defining the differential, given the definition of the components of $A\otimes B$. Take $(A\otimes B)^2$ as an example. Then by the definition here we have
$$(A\otimes B)^2 = (A^2\otimes B^0)\oplus (A^1\otimes B^1)\oplus (A^0\otimes B^2)$$
But this means that elements of $(A\otimes B)^2$ would be of the form
$$(a_2\otimes b_0, a_1\otimes b_1, a_0\otimes b_2)  \tag{3}$$
with $a_i\in A^i$ and $b_i\in B^i$, rather than something of the form $a\otimes b$ which is required for the differential $d_{A\otimes B}$. How can you identify this with a pure tensor? You surely can't make the identification
$$(A^2\otimes B^0)\oplus (A^1\otimes B^1)\oplus (A^0\otimes B^2)\simeq \left(\bigoplus_{i=0}^2 A^{2-i}\right)\otimes\left(\bigoplus_{i=0}^2 B^{i}\right)  \tag{4}$$
mainly because I'm fairly certain that that just isn't how tensor products and direct sums interact, but even if it was I'm not sure how you'd apply the differential $d_A$ to $A^2\oplus A^1\oplus A^0$ for example.
If the pure tensor representation for the definition is just for convenience, then my next question would be in this example how would you apply the differential $d_{A\otimes B}$ to $(a_2\otimes b_0, a_1\otimes b_1, a_0\otimes b_2)$?
I'm a little rusty with all this, so willing to concede there may be something basic about algebras/tensor products/direct sums that I'm missing or forgetting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

the differential is induced on the basis given by pure tensors and then extended to the full degree. In particular $(a_2\otimes b_0,a_1\otimes b_1, a_0\otimes b_2)\mapsto (d a_1 \otimes b_0 \pm a_2 \otimes db_0 + d a_1 \otimes b_1 \pm a_1 \otimes d b_1 + da_0\otimes b_2 \pm a_0\otimes d b_2)$. Does that clarify it?

@Felix  Ahh of course! Yes that does clear it up, thank you! Feel free to put that as an answer and I'd be happy to upvote and mark it as accepted :)

the differential is induced on the basis given by pure tensors and then extended to the full degree. In particular
$$(a_2⊗b_0,a_1⊗b_1,a_0⊗b_2)\mapsto (da_1⊗b_0±a_2⊗db_0+da_1⊗b_1±a_1⊗db_1+da_0⊗b_±a_0⊗db_2).$$
Since I love transparancy: the above answer was copied from my comment that seemingly sufficed as answer!
